# Why does parse_git_branch fail ONLY in Docker terminal window

Tags: bash, docker

Why would running a bash terminal under Docker Quickstart Terminal report

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

after every bash command I type, whereas it works fine if I run Terminal directly?

On my Mac (OS 10.9.5) in my ~/.bash_profile I define a function to show the git branch in my prompt and it works fine when I run Terminal UNLESS I'm running Terminal via the Docker Quickstart Terminal.

In both cases (running Terminal normally, or via Docker Quickstart Terminal) `echo $BASH_VERSION` shows the same result (3.2.53(1)-release).

In both cases, if I `cat ~/.bash_profile` I see the same thing, and towards the bottom the function is clearly defined:

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Comment: The quick start terminal may not be starting a login shell, in which case `.bash_profile` isn't sourced. Check the output of `ps`; login shells show up as `-bash`; ordinary interactive shells as `bash`.

Comment: @chepner manually running `source ~/.bash_profile` does fix the issue. When I run `ps` I see both -bash and bash not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Quickstart Terminal does not appear to start a login shell, so `.bash_profile` is not executed. Typically, you would set the value of `PS1` in `.bashrc` so that it is defined for *all* interactive shells, which is what most (all?) Linux terminal emulators start.

In Mac OS X, terminal emulators usually start login shells, since they themselves are not started *from* a shell, but by Finder.

Good practice is to set your prompt in `.bashrc`, but to source that file from `.bash_profile` under OS X.